# Deno: Provide Polyfills for Node.js Built-Ins

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, polyfills, deno

Does Deno have a way to shim/polyfill Node.js modules?

That is, let's say I have a typescript file that's part of a Node.js project, and it looks something like this

```
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';

function hello() {
  console.log(performance.performance.timeOrigin)
  console.log("Hello World")
}

export {
  hello
}
```

I want to use this module in a deno program, so I do something like this

```
import {hello} from './some-module.ts'

function main() {
  hello()
}
```

However, I can't do this because there's no `perf_hooks` module in Deno.

```
% deno run main.ts 
Check file:///private/tmp/main.ts
error: TS2305 [ERROR]: Module '"deno:///none.d.ts"' has no exported member 'performance'.
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    at file:///private/tmp/some-module.ts:1:10
```

I would like to write my own version of `perf_hooks` that implements the properties and methods I need, and then tell Deno *Hey -- whenever anyone wants `perf_hook` use my module instead*.

Does Deno have anything built in that would let me do this? If not is there some common practive/bundling technique that the Deno community uses to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use https://deno.land/x/std/node. It provide some Node's built-in modules. For external modules, you can take a look at https://esm.sh (The syntax is `https://esm.sh/<npm-pkg>`.

And if you want to use it like NodeJS environment, you can do the following:

```
import { ... } from "module"; // Let's use NodeJS "module" module for this
```

Then specify an [import map](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps)

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "module": "https://deno.land/std/node/module.ts"
  }
}
```

Run with the `--import-map` flag

```sh
$ deno run --import-map=/path/to/import_map.json your_file.ts
```